# Using current URL (with specific id) in jquery ajax request

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, url

I've looked through similar-titled questions on here on SO, but have yet to find someone with the same issue. Using jQuery, I'm trying to make an ajax request without having to specify the entire `url` parameter. For example, if I'm on page `www.foo.com/bar` and would like to send an ajax request to `www.foo.com/bar/woot`, I can simply set the `url` parameter to `/bar/woot` which results in a request to `www.foo.com/bar/woot` - sounds good.

But, this works in the case that page `bar` is at the root of the site. In my case, I'm on page `www.foo.com/users/1` (I'm developing a RoR application that has multiple users), and would like to send a request to `www.foo.com/users/1/bar`. I figured that simply setting the `url` parameter to `bar` (without the preceeding `/` to begin at the root) would work, and it *sort-of-kind-of did*. When setting the `url` parameter to `bar`, the ajax request was made to `www.foo.com/users/bar` (obviously, leaving out the user id, `/1/`, that I had hoped to see sandwiched between `users` and `bar`).

I also searched with the ruby-on-rails tag and didn't see anything about this being a RoR-specific issue. I could obviously get around this issue by passing the user id to the function and simply inserting it into the url, i.e. `url: "/users/"+user_id+"/bar", but that's lame.

The strange thing to me, is that the `/1/` is definitely part of the url (if I'm not mistaken), not something like a `#1` fragment that wouldn't be a part of the request - so why is it getting dropped?

**UPDATE**
There are simple ways to accomplish what I want in jQuery, such as changing the `url` argument to `window.location.href()+"/bar"` as the `.href()` call will include the `/1/` in the current url, however I was wondering if there is an explanation as to *why* just specifying `bar` for the `url` argument does not include the `/1/` in the constructed url used by the ajax request.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The simple solution is to tack `window.location.href` in front, but really you should be using your routes to determine the location of your resources.

Comment: I'm obviously using routes to specify the location of my resources, `bar` is a member of the `users` resource - this is why I need the correct id. My question was client-side not server-side.

Answer (score 0):

This will work.

```
var current_href = window.location.href()
window.location.replace(current_href + '/bar')
```

this will load the url `www.foo.com/users/1/bar`

Comment: I don't want to replace the current location of the URL actually in the browser, this is for the `url` argument of the jQuery ajax request. `window.location.href()` _does_ get what I want, but the `window.location.replace()` is a little off.

Comment: Also, I updated the question. First, thanks for the answer, but the question is more about the construction of the `url` argument depending on what is provided to the ajax request.

Comment: According to your update, what i understood is, you are trying to send an **ajax** request, in which u want to pass the url accordingly. So am i correct?

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the question - I would like the for the URL of the page to stay the same, i.e. `www.foo.com/users/1/` should stay. In the ajax request, which takes `url` as an argument, I want to pass `www.foo.com/users/1/bar`. This can be accomplished by getting the current URL (like with `window.location.href()`) and simply appending `bar` to it, so the argument in full would be `url: window.location.href()+"bar"`, but I'm wondering why the argument cannot simply be `url: "bar"` - this builds the url `www.foo.com/users/bar`, rather than the expected `www.foo.com/users/1/bar`.